# How do I use the MCMC method to find the joint posterior of 4 parameters ($\lambda$,$\lambda_s$,$\mu$,$\beta$) of exponential distributions

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Essentially, the problem statement is as follows.
I have 2 functions in reliability theory called MTTF(Mean time to failure) and Availablity, both with inputs as $\lambda$,$\lambda_s$,$\mu$ & $\beta$.

Two parameter Gamma priors are assumed for each of them. We assume the prior distributions of all the system parameters are independent.Thus, the prior joint distribution of ($\lambda$,$\lambda_s$,$\mu$,$\beta$) is taken to be the product of the prior distributions of each parameter. Proceeding analogously, we obtain the joint posterior distribution given by the product of conjugate priors.

I haven't understood the author's methodology(link given below) for finding the joint posterior. How should I go about the simulation?.I felt that Gibbs Sampling should be employed. Also, if someone could explain the acceptance and rejectance in multivariate Metropolis Hastings it would be great.
If there are any good books for learning more about this please do suggest them.

The link to the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1569190X07001591. Please refer to section 3 and 4 in the paper mentioned above.

Thanking you in advance.

PS:- I am a student, please forgive me if there are any lapses in my knowledge or statements.

Comment: could you please clarify which parameters are inputs to which function? i.e., do the two lambdas go into the MFFT? A formal definition of each function would be helpful. Additionally, there appears to be four parameters: two lambdas and mu and beta. What are their respective prior distributions?

Comment: regarding your reference request, what is your background in mathematics and statistics? That will help tailor reference recommendations to you.

Comment: @silly.deer Both functions take all four parameters as input arguements. The formal definition of the function is given in the paper (whose link I've provided). Also, I am an undergrad student majoring in Mathematics